# Comparing output of two versions of a stored procedure using a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I have two versions of a stored proc and want to make sure that their outputs are exactly the same. My unit tests and functional tests do verify that the two versions are the same. However before using the newer version of the proc on a live environment I want to make sure that they match.

I am trying to do the following on a copy of the live DB:

1. Start a transaction.
2. Call stored procedure sproc_v1  (internally the proc modifies table T1).
3. Select * into T1_v1 from T1 (with a condition to filter out those rows affected by the sproc_v1)
4. Rollback the transaction (so that I have same initial conditions for running V2
5. Call stored procedure sproc_v2
6. Select * into T1_v2 from T1

Well obviously after step 3 - the values in T1_v1 are also rolled back. May be I can dump the data into a file and compare the files. Was wondering if there is another way to do this kind of matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big is your result set?

One approach might be to declare xml variables

```
DECLARE @xml1 XML, @xml2 XML;
```

... and use

```
SET @xml1=(SELECT ... FOR XML RAW) --without the "INTO SomeTable"! Same with `@xml2`
```

At the end you can use

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(@xml1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))=CAST(@xml2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) THEN ...`
```

Make sure, that there are no timestamps or other variable content, which would disturb of course...

### UPDATE

You might use a declared table variable, which lives as long as your job lives and is not affected by the rollback:

Instead of your `SELECT * INTO SomeTable` you use `INSERT INTO @tableVariable (col1, col2, ...) SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM ...`.

Just use the existing declaration of your table to create the table variable. No need to type in all columns manually...

Comment: I tried out the XML but as my result sets were large and the xml was getting truncated. Table variables seem like the way to go.

Comment: what did you mean by 'just use the existing declaration of your table to create the table variable' ? AFAIK one cannot select into a table variable correct?

Comment: @shekhar Correct, but you can copy and paste the declaration to avoid so much erronous typing. You write `DECLARE @tbl TABLE(copy'n'paste the declaration of T1 here)`

Comment: got it :) I was wondering if you some trick up your sleeve :)

Answer (score 1):

I always use excel for this. Paste the results of the first stored procedure in sheet 1, the results of the second stored procedure in the second sheet and compare the values in the third sheet.

Comment: Well - this is what I was doing .. excel or Beyond Compare :).